# Why is the AVG not returning anything in my Where clause in SQL?

Tags: sql

The question ask,

"List   the customer    name    and phone   number  for customers   whose   credit  limit   is  less    than    the average credit  limit.  (Customers  table)"

So far I have

```
SELECT customerName, phone
FROM Customers 
WHERE creditLimit < (SELECT AVG (creditLimit)
                           FROM Products);
```

Yet this code is not returning anything, what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if `Products` has a credit limit.  If you qualify your column names, you will immediately see your error:

```
SELECT c.customerName, c.phone
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.creditLimit < (SELECT AVG(p.creditLimit)
                       FROM Products p
                      );
```

In other words, you should be using `Customers` in the subquery.  What is happening is that the query is interpreted like this:

```
SELECT c.customerName, c.phone
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.creditLimit < (SELECT AVG(c.creditLimit)
                       FROM Products p
                      );
```

That is, the subquery is using the `creditLimit` from the row being compared, rather than from the table referenced in the subquery (because there is no such column).  A value is never less than itself, so this never evaluates to true.

A more important lesson to learn:  *always* qualify your column names, so you don't ever have a problem like this again.

Comment: Thank you so much!